# What word means the opposite of "supportive"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I mean supportive in the sense of "giving help or assistance". Unsupportive denotes a lack of aid, but I'm looking for a word that expresses the opposite of support. This word would be used to describe someone who is impeding my efforts or hindering me in some way. Ideally, this word would not imply villainous behavior, just perhaps working at cross purposes.

I might use it to say, "Not only are you not being supportive, you are being ...." or "Can we work together on this? As it is, your ... actions upset me."

Comment: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/supportive/antonyms Depending on context

Comment: *counterproductive* ?

Comment: @Kris, counterproductive is a good choice, thanks! I'd accept it if you posted it as an answer.

Comment: "Obstructive" perhaps?

Comment: "Undermining" is the first word that comes to mind, but then you probably already saw that one when you checked a thesaurus, right?

Comment: "Inimical" looks like what you want (from Kris' list).

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, I checked more than one thesaurus (Roget's, thesaurus.com, et al). As you can see from the variety of answers posted, there are some subtleties in meaning that prevent there from being a clear antonym to supportive. Undermining doesn't fit into the sample sentences I wrote. It sound odd to me to describe a person as "undermining", though their actions might be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Obstructive** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obstructive)

> *adjective* 2. Causing or tending to cause deliberate difficulties and delays
>   *"That typifies his attitude throughout the case uncooperative, obstructive and difficult."*

Answer (score 2):

I would think *counterproductive* can come pretty close.

[counterproductive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counterproductive) (ODO)

> adjective
>   Having the opposite of the desired effect

Usage:
Oliver Gassmann, Fiona Schweitzer, *Management of the Fuzzy Front End of Innovation,* Springer Sc. & Bus. Media, 2013, p.[8](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4HnABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22supportive%20and%20counterproductive%22#v=onepage&q=%22supportive%20and%20counterproductive%22&f=false) (GoogleBooks)

> The art of managing the fuzzy front end (of innovation) ... is the art of identifying and understanding contradictory and complementary forces, supportive and counterproductive influences, and of providing the necessary framework, resources, and conditions to cope with these forces and influences.

The above example shows *supportive* and *counterproductive* in direct contrast.

Answer (score 1):

**Frustrate** seems a good fit. — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frustrate)

> to prevent (efforts, plans, etc.) from succeeding : to keep (someone) from doing something

Answer (score 0):

**discouraging**

[dictionary.com definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discouraging)

> 1.
>   to deprive of courage, hope, or confidence; dishearten; dispirit.
>
> 2.
>   to dissuade (usually followed by from).

Used in your example sentence: "Can we work together on this? As it is, your *discouraging* actions upset me."

.

**antagonistic**

[dictionary.com definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antagonistic?s=t)

> 1.
>   acting in opposition; opposing, especially mutually.

Used in your example sentence: "Not only are you not being supportive, you are being *antagonistic*."

Comment: Does "antagonistic" work as the antonym of "supportive"?

Comment: @Rathony, in the way the OP wants it, I believe it does

Answer (score 0):

> "Not only are you not being supportive, you are <del>being</del> [a
>   **hindrance**]  ...." or "Can we work together on this? As it is, your
>   [**interference**] <del>actions</del> upset[s] me."

**Hindrance**

> : a person or thing that makes a situation difficult
>   : a person or thing that hinders someone or something
>   : the act of making it difficult for someone to act or for something to be done
>   : the act of hindering someone or something

"Hindrance." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 22 June 2016.

**Interference**

> 1a :  the act or process of interfering
>   1b :  something that interferes :  obstruction

"Interference." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 22 June 2016.

Answer (score -1):

After looking at [powerthesaurus.org/supportive/antonyms](http://powerthesaurus.org/supportive/antonyms) thanks to @Kris, I think the word **contrary** fits, in the sense of "very opposed in nature or character or purpose". It's not ideal -- I typically would only use this word to describe a child.